# Reference expression match in case statement

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to reference the expression match in the command list of a case statement? In other words, instead of doing this:

```
case $(returns_a_string.sh) in
  foo) echo "foo" ;;
  bar) echo "bar" ;;
  *) echo "The string returned was not foo or bar" ;;
esac
```

Can I do this:

```
case $(returns_a_string.sh) in
  foo|bar) echo "$expression_match" ;;
  *) echo "The string returned was not foo or bar" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're invoking it does not store the result, so you cannot recall it later in your `echo` call.

Try this instead:

```
string="$(returns_a_string.sh)"
case "$string" in
  foo|bar) echo "$string" ;;
  *) echo "The string returned was not foo or bar" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the stdout of `$(returns_a_string.sh)` to a variable first, then use that later.

Comment: You mean you can save the value it outputs. Its return code comes from its exit code, which was probably `0` ("success").

Comment: Yes - I meant to say set the stdout, edited my answer.